# Find the inductance of the copper coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

I have copper coil Its length is 20 meter, diameter is 1.66mm. How can I find the inductance of the coil (with out applying the voltage)?

---

I got it, actually. I wound the coil on a hard paper, the number of turns is 180.

$$L = \frac{relative\;permeability \cdot absolute\;permeability 
            \cdot turns^2 \cdot area}{length}$$

$$L= \frac{1 \cdot 4 \cdot 3.14 \cdot 10^{-7} \cdot 180^2 \cdot 1.66 \cdot 10^{-3}}{20}$$

$$L=3.25 \cdot 10^{-6} \;henry$$

Again one question is rising. I wound the coil on a hard paper. Does that paper have any relative permeability value? Because I assigned it as a 1 (I assumed it is the same relative permeability of air, which is 1).

Comment: It's all about the shape, the presence of ferromagnetic or conductive materials and number of turns. The wire material is irrelevant and to a large extent so is the wire diameter.

Comment: Nobody can contribute to this without knowing the shape of the solenoid/coil. I'm seeing 180 turns and an area of 1.66E-3 but that is the wire diameter. Also, the length will not be 20 metres as you appear to have put. I think your calcs are wrong.

Comment: Is the coil really 20m long?

Comment: yes , the length is 20m and the shape is cylindrical

Answer (score 2):

Inductors are highly relative to their shape and so many practical aspects. If you wanna know inductance actually, best and more reliable way is to use a inductance meter or use a circuit like 555 base circuits:

http://www.electronicshub.org/lc-meter-circuit-using-555-timer/

you can measure frequency output by any other ways instead of 8051.

Best Way is Measurement...